# what is the correct address for BUSD Testnet for transferring with Web3/Metamask?

Tags: token, solidity, bsc, bep20, bscscan

I have a requirement of building **Smart contract** where BUSD is concerned.After googling, i came to know about **2 BUSD address** and I don't know which one is going to used in smart contract implementation(**Testing Mode**).

1st Contract Address - **0x78867BbEeF44f2326bF8DDd1941a4439382EF2A7**

2nd Contract Address - **0xed24fc36d5ee211ea25a80239fb8c4cfd80f12ee**

it's confusing and when searching online doesn't seem to find any answers.When I try to get free BUSD from **faucet**(https://testnet.binance.org/faucet-smart), 2nd contract address is used.but when i make an transcation after approving, "Insufficient Funds" error was thrown instead. If 1st contract address is genuine instead then how to get free BUSD of that address.

Solidity function i'm using

```
depositToken.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 5e18);
```

Where depositToken is the BUSD Address.

**Insufficient Fund error:** https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x048f89ecf26a7cbbaa4adb359b5e884ec6d7e6c8a4cd1a8242a138b8cbb6fadd